# AWS EC2 DNS not responding to Rails app deployment on CentOS 6 with capistrano

Tags: amazon-web-services, centos6, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to deploy a small rails app w/ sqlite3 to a micro AWS EC2 CentOS 6  instance using capistrano (after not having much success with nginx & passenger). I follow this site to deploy my app

https://mattbrictson.com/build-and-deploy-a-rails-vps-part-2

and the deploy is a success but the AWS instance DNS is responding with `page isn’t working` and `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. What's weird is when I navigate to my DNS the console says `Navigated to data:text/html,chromewebdata` which is not right. I tried Googling the problem but not many had similar problems. It's difficult to track this when the deployer was a success when I ran `bundle exec cap production deploy` from my mac (not inside AWS server) and there were no errors. Does anyone have a similar problem and know a fix for this silent deployment problem?

I deployed the app as a `deployer` user at `/var/www/texter/` path and the user has access to this folder inside the AWS ec2 instance.

Port 80 and 8080 are open in my AWS security group setting so I don't think that's a problem either. I tell my firewall to accept the port 8080 and 80 with this command (correct me if I'm wrong) below but that didn't do anything.

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT`

`sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

Here is what I did to set up the server as a `deployer` user, which is standard for a rails app:

```
sudo yum install -y git-core zlib zlib-devel gcc-c++ patch readline readline-devel libyaml-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel make bzip2 autoconf automake libtool bison curl sqlite-devel

# preparring rbenv, ruby, rails, nodejs
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc

exec $SHELL
rbenv install -v 2.1.0
rbenv global 2.1.0
echo "gem: --no-document" > ~/.gemrc
gem install bundler
gem install rails -v 4.2.6 -V
rbenv rehash
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum install nodejs
```

after that I set up my rails with capistrano with these content in the `config/deploy.rb`, `Capfile`, `/config/deploy/production.rb` (all of them are same as the tutorial link I posted above but posting for reference).

inside `config/deploy.rb`

```
set :application, "texter"
set :repo_url, "my_github_repo"
set :linked_dirs, %w(
  bin log vendor/bundle public/system
  tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets
)
set :puma_bind, "tcp://0.0.0.0:8080"
```

`Capfile`

```
# Load DSL and set up stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Include default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require "capistrano/puma"
# require 'capistrano/passenger'

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

for my content in `/config/deploy/production.rb`:

```
server "PUBLIC-IP-FROM-AWS",
       :user => "deployer",
       :roles => %w(web app db)
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with some help from this page

[Can not access EC2 server via IP address](https://serverfault.com/questions/464292/can-not-access-ec2-server-via-ip-address)

Option #2 solved my problem and hope it will help some others. A different problem popped up though. I got the server running in the public IP but `puma` is not running; the deployment message claims everything was working fine. I resolved by bypassing this and run `bundle exec passenger start` inside the `/var/www/myappName/current` path as root and that kickstarted nginx engine to proxy the localhost server. Resolving puma server is a completely different problem which I might ask in another post.